# Rationale behind Good–Turing frequency estimation?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, multinomial-distribution

[Good–Turing frequency estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation) is  a smoothing estimator for estimating a multinomial distribution. It seems very convoluted.

1. From mathematical statistics point of view, what is the rationale
   behind the construction of Good–Turing frequency estimation?
2. Is it [a shrinkage estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinkage_estimator)?
3. Is it based on the posterior distribution with respect to some prior distribution on the parameters, in
   Bayesian inference view?
4. Is it not [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing), is it? What type of smoothing is it?